# Problem with stopping NDSolve after a condition is met

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, numerics, warning-messages

I'm trying to write a piece of Mathematica code that is essentially a differential equation solver that needs to take a specified function $V[t,q]$, and then numerically solves the differential equation $\ddot{\phi}[t] = -3\sqrt{\frac{1}{3}(\frac{1}{2}\dot{\phi}^2 + V)}\dot{\phi} - \partial_\phi V$.
The issue I'm having is that I need NDSolve to stop trying to solve when a certain condition is met, specifically when either of the functions $\varepsilon_i = \frac{1}{2}(\frac{\partial_\phi V}{V})^2$ or $|\eta_i| = |\frac{\partial_\phi^2 V}{V}|$ gets greater than 1. Currently I'm running the code with a test function $V = \Lambda(1-\lambda^{-q}\phi[t]^q)^2$

```
Clear parameters used in the potential

Clear[λ, q]

q = 4;

Define potential and derivatives

V[t_, q_] := Λ (1 - λ^-q ϕ[t]^q)^2

Subscript[V, ϕ][t_, q_] := \!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(∂\), \(ϕ[t]\)]\(V[t, q]\)\)

Subscript[V, ϕϕ][t_, q_] := \!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(∂\), \(ϕ[t], ϕ[t]\)]\(V[t, q]\)\)

Define Hubble parameter

H[t_, q_] := Sqrt[1/3 (1/2 ϕdot[t]^2 + V[t, q])]

Slow-roll parameters

Subscript[ϵ, i][t_, q_] := 1/2 (Subscript[V, ϕ][t, q]/V[t, q])^2

Subscript[η, i][t_, q_] := Subscript[V, ϕϕ][t, q]/V[t, q]

Setup the Klein-Gordon equation and the e-folds

ϕddot[t_] := -3 H[t, q] ϕdot[t] - Subscript[V, ϕ][t, q]

lnadot[t_] := H[t, q]



λrange = 2;
ϕdotrange = 2;


For[λset = 1, λset < λrange, λset++,
 λ = λset*1;
 For[ϕdotset = 1, ϕdotset < ϕdotrange, ϕdotset++,
  ϕdotinit = ϕdotset/100;
  sol = NDSolve[{ϕ'[t] == ϕdot[t], ϕdot'[t] == ϕddot[t], 
     lna'[t] == lnadot[t], ϕ[0] == 0, ϕdot[0] == ϕdotinit, 
     lna[0] == 0, Λ == 1}, {ϕ, ϕdot, 
     lna, Λ}, {t, 0, 10^16},
    Method -> {"EventLocator", 
      "Event" :> {Subscript[ϵ, i][t, q] > 1, 
        Abs[Subscript[η, i][t, q]] > 1}, 
      "EventAction" :> Throw[tend = t, "StopIntegration"]}];
  ]]
```

The issue is that Mathematica does not seem happy with me using the conditions $\varepsilon_i > 1$ and $|\eta_i|>1$ and returns the error

```
NDSolve::nbnum1: The function value Abs[(32 Λ ϕ[0.000307756]^6-24 Λ ϕ[0.000307756]^2 (1-Power[<<2>>]))/(Λ (1-ϕ[<<1>>]^4)^2)]>1 is not True or False when the arguments are {0.000307756,0.000177687,3.07592*10^-6,0.00999467,0.577365,0.00999467,-0.0173117}.
```

but works perfectly fine if I explicitly evaluate $\varepsilon_i $ and $\eta_i$ and instead use

```
sol = NDSolve[{ϕ'[t] == ϕdot[t], ϕdot'[
      t] == ϕddot[t], 
    lna'[t] == lnadot[t], ϕ[0] == 
     0, ϕdot[0] == ϕdotinit, lna[0] == 0, 
    Λ == 1}, {ϕ, ϕdot, lna, Λ}, {t, 0, 10^16},
    Method -> {"EventLocator", 
     "Event" :> {(
         2 q^2 λ^(-2 q) ϕ[t]^(-2 + 
           2 q))/(1 - λ^-q ϕ[t]^q)^2 > 1, 
       Abs[(2 q^2 λ^(-2 q) Λ ϕ[t]^(-2 + 2 q) - 
          2 (-1 + q) q λ^-q Λ ϕ[t]^(-2 + q) (1 - λ^-q ϕ[t]^q))/(
         Λ (1 - λ^-q ϕ[t]^q)^2)] > 1}, 
     "EventAction" :> Throw[tend = t, "StopIntegration"]}];
```

I'd like to know if there's a workaround so that I can just specify $V$ and any parameters and not have to explicitly evaluate $\varepsilon_i$ and $\eta_i$ . Apologies if I haven't included all the relevant information to the problem or if I've made some basic errors, my experience with Mathematica is quite limited.

Comment: `WhenEvent`  work?

Comment: @cvgmt Sort of, it returns a different error - ""The length of the derivative operator Derivative[1] in \phi'[t] is not the same as the number of arguments"